# obj.closest_point_on_mesh ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, mesh, objects

I am trying to check if an imported obj file is colliding with others by trying tu use the `closest_point_on_mesh` function. Here is the loop:

```
    coords = [(the_object.matrix_world * v.co) for v in the_object.data.vertices]
    for p_obj in list_of_passive_bodies:
        for c in coords:
            mesh_inside = is_inside(c,p_obj.name,max_dist=0.1)
            if mesh_inside == True:
                break
            else:
                continue
            break
```

and the function `is_inside`:

```
 def is_inside(p,obj,max_dist= 1.84467e+19):
        point, normal, face = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(p, max_dist)
        p2 = point-p
        v = p2.dot(normal)
        print(v)
        return not(v < 0.0)
```

`coords` is the list of vertices of the imported mesh from the obj file and `list_of_passive_bodies` is the list of already existing objects in the scene.

For example, `p_obj` returns :

> bpy_struct, Object("Blob.obj_0_Blob.002")

and `c` returns :

> Vector (-7.2836, 2.1763, 5.8258)

I constantly get a

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation of closest_point_on_mesh: https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_mesh

> Return (**result, location, normal, index**):
>
> - **result**, boolean
> - **location**, The location on the object closest to the point, float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf]
> - **normal**, The face normal at the closest point, float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf]
> - **index**, The face index, -1 when original data isn’t available, int in [-inf, inf]

So the function is returning 4 values, but you only unpack 3.
It should be called like this:

```
result, point, normal, face = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(p, max_dist)
```